# Как сделать, чтобы стили swiper slider не перекрывали стили элемента?

Tags: html, css, slider, слайдер, swiper

Есть идея создать оболочку для слайдов, но может у кого-нибудь есть другие идеи?

до инициализации swiper слайдера:

```
<div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image: url('img.png');">
```

После:

```
<div class="swiper-slide" rule="group" aria-label="3 / 8" style="width: 349.5px; margin-right: 15px;"> </div>
```

html inline стили перекрыты

Comment: а какой результат вы хотите получить? Свайпер удаляет картинку?

Comment: Сделать оболочку - правильный вариант

Comment: Да, удаляет. Сделаю оболочку;)